# SEO And AJAX Sites

Tags: seo, search-engine, single-page-application

Is it possible to help search engines by giving them a list of urls to crawl? It might be hard to make the site SEO friendly when using heavy AJAX logic. Let's say that the user chooses a category, then a sub-category and a product. It seems unnecessary to give categories and subcategories urls. But giving only products a url makes sense. When I see the url for the product, I can make the application navigate to that product. So, is it possible to use robots.txt or some other method to direct search engines to the urls I designate?

I am open to other suggestions if this somehow does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you're describing is called a sitemap -- it's a list of pages on your site which search engines can use to help them crawl your web site.

There are a couple ways of formatting a sitemap, but by far the easiest is to just list out all the URLs in a text file available on your web site -- one per line -- and reference it in `robots.txt` like so:

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.txt
```

Here's Google's documentation on the topic: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en